# Making a 'facebook' style feed using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a facebook style news feed on my webpage that combines user input from multiple tables into a feed.

Would the best way to approach this be:

(1) Using mySQL Join Queries
(2) Using mySQL single queries from multiple tables into an Array.
(3) Another way?

Thanks.

Edit:

The structure of my Databases are as follows:

```
1 User (Table: User)
Mutliple Blogs per user (Table: Blog)
Mutliple Content Upload per user (Table: Content)
```

What I am trying to achieve is a query that will collect the defined users ID's blog post and content uploads and display them in chronological order.

Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult to answer without knowing anything about your database schema (consider editing your question to add some details), but you may wish to consider creating a [View](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/views.html) that you could then retrieve and present your news feed from with a single, simple query.

Comment: Could I using something like UNION to mash the information I need together?

Answer (score 1):

If there is going to be a lot of data it is good to have a separate table that holds your "feed". That way, you don't have a lot of overhead each time you do your query.